# ZXing.Result appears to always be null in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, zxing

I have done some extensive searching on this issue and finding very few support documents.

I am trying to take an already existing image [Download here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B42XN3-a_tIoanlvVVpnenRoSUU/view) with a simple barcode on it and process the barcode in a PCL layer of the project.

Here is the code i am processing:

```
private void ReadBarcode()
        {
            try
            {
                var imageBytes =imagingHelper.GetImage(ImagePath);
                var width = imagingHelper.GetWidth(ImagePath);
                var height = imagingHelper.GetHeight(ImagePath);
                LuminanceSource source = new ZXing.RGBLuminanceSource(imageBytes, (int)width, (int)height);
                HybridBinarizer hb = new HybridBinarizer(source);
                var a = hb.createBinarizer(source);
                BinaryBitmap bBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(a);
                BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
                reader.Options.TryHarder = true;

                MultiFormatReader reader1 = new MultiFormatReader();
                try
                {
                    var r = reader1.decodeWithState(bBitmap);
                    var result = reader.Decode(source);
                    var result2 = reader.DecodeMultiple(source);
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    HandleError("ReadBarcode Error: ",ex.Message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HandleError("ReadBarcode Error: ", ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

for the image helper (at the android level)

```
public override uint GetWidth(string photoPath)
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.InPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.Argb8888;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(photoPath, options);
            return bitmap.GetBitmapInfo().Width;
        }

        public override uint GetHeight(string photoPath)
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.InPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.Argb8888;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(photoPath, options);
            return bitmap.GetBitmapInfo().Height;
        }
        public override byte[] GetImage(string photoPath)
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.InPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.Argb8888;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(photoPath, options);

            var width = bitmap.GetBitmapInfo().Width;
            var height = bitmap.GetBitmapInfo().Height;
            int size = bitmap.RowBytes * (int)bitmap.GetBitmapInfo().Height;
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.Allocate(size);
            bitmap.CopyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[byteBuffer.Remaining()];
            byteBuffer.Get(byteArray);
            return byteArray;
        }
```

Every single one of my results are turning up null and i'm unsure how to proceed. I have downloaded the latest beta package and on xamarin forms 2.1.0.6529

any help in this would be great i'm not sure if there is something wrong or what.

I should also note that even at the android level it appears to not return a result.